# Creating SafeArray with user defined type objects

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, interop

I am using Interoperability concept between Delphi and c#. I created classes in c#, and imported those classes to delphi project as com objects.
The class declaration in c# code

```
public class HotelAvailNotifRQ : IHotelAvailNotifRQ
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    public IAvailStatusMessage[] AvailStatusMessagesField;

    public IAvailStatusMessage[] AvailStatusMessages
    {
        get { return AvailStatusMessagesField; }
        set { AvailStatusMessagesField = value; }
    }
}
```

And when I import this class as com object to delphi that will be like

```
IHotelAvailNotifRQ = interface(IDispatch)
  ['{2F7C57D7-256A-3102-A4C6-FD081C8342B4}']
  function Get_AvailStatusMessages: PSafeArray; safecall;
  procedure Set_AvailStatusMessages(pRetVal: PSafeArray); safecall;
  property AvailStatusMessages: PSafeArray read Get_AvailStatusMessages  write Set_AvailStatusMessages;
end;
```

I can create IAvailStatusMessage object successfully. But, while I am putting this object into the PSafeArray by using function

```
SafeArrayPutElement(HotelAvailNotifRQ.AvailStatusMessages, Idx, AvailStatusMessage)
```

I am getting the error like **"the parameter is incorrect"**. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you want to use LPArray types? You won't be able to access the IAvailStatusMessage interface instances through COM, I'm afraid. Use a regular .Net class in-between, which encapsulate the interfaces, then publish a regular List<WrapperIAvailableStatusMessage>.

Comment: Hi Arnaud, I think According to COM objects, we can only publish interfaces. I did not test that. And, Is it possible to publish List from manged code to unmanaged code? if possible, then it would solve my problem easily. If you have any reference link, please send it.

Comment: `Idx` - what type of this parameter?

Comment: Its Integer type of parameter. I tested with single dimensional array of integers. But, it didn't work out well.

Comment: if `idx` is integer, try `SafeArrayPutElement(HotelAvailNotifRQ.AvailStatusMessages, @Idx, AvailStatusMessage)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of struggling found the solution for the problem. After chaning the both sides code as,

Delphi side code

```
var
  varAvailStatusMessages : Variant;
begin
    varAvailStatusMessages := VarArrayCreate([0, AvailStatusMessages.Count], varDispatch);
    varAvailStatusMessages[asmIdx] := AvailStatusMessage;
    Result.AvailStatusMessages := PSafeArray(TVarData(varAvailStatusMessages).VArray);
end;
```

.Net side code

```
public class HotelAvailNotifRQ : IHotelAvailNotifRQ
{
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
   public IAvailStatusMessage[] AvailStatusMessagesField;

   public IAvailStatusMessage[] AvailStatusMessages
   {
    get { return AvailStatusMessagesField; }
    set { AvailStatusMessagesField = value; }
   }
}
```

Thanks for the reference,
http://blog.virtec.org/2008/07/the-mysteries-of-psafearray/